# Google Chrome on iOS recognizes my site as text instead of HTML

Tags: html, ios, google-chrome, mobile

I'm trying to figure out a reason for a website to display the source code instead of actually reading the HTML of a certain site:

http://europalace.com

The site works great on ANY other device / browser and any combination you can come up with, not on Chrome for iOS thou.

Any help or lead would be very much appreciated.

Checking with a W3 Validator I get the notice the site is text/html doctyped (which is not), not sure for the reason of that but might be.

Note that its more or less the only website in the world that this issue occurs on.

Comment: try changing the doctype, make sure it is correct!

Comment: I wish it was such a simple issue :) Every known doctype have been tried, I believe its something that might cause iOS' Chrome to read something else